# Entry widgets are not created when using place method instead of grid and also it is not creating any error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The below code, i have used to create a entry widgets dynamically using class. The problem is when i used *grid()* method (in class)it worked however if i use *place()* method entry widgets are not created.  I doubt the problem may be because of the last line addition in the grid method of class(look at the last line of code). How can I solve the problem that got created while using the place method?

***Working***

The sequence is :

1. Start with submit function
2. goes to while loop
3. while loop to EntryRow calss
4. coming back to while ( 3,4 repeated until the condition fails )
5. ending while loop and goes to extract data function
6. stop

```
class EntryRow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, counter,dx, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.counter = counter
        self.dx = dx
        
        self.entry_box_1 = Entry(self, width=15,) # bg="lightblue")
        self.entry_box_2 = Entry(self, width=18,) # bg="lightblue")
        self.entry_box_3 = Entry(self, width=20,) # bg="lightblue")
        self.entry_box_4 = Entry(self, width=18,) # bg="lightblue")
        self.entry_box_5 = Entry(self, width=18,) # bg="lightblue")
        self.entry_box_6 = Entry(self, width=18,) #bg="lightblue")
        self.entry_box_7 = Entry(self, width=18,) #bg="lightblue")
        

        
        self.entry_box_1.place(x = dx, y = 130) 
        self.entry_box_2.place(x = dx, y = 160)
        self.entry_box_3.place(x = dx, y = 220)
        self.entry_box_4.place(x = dx, y = 250)
        self.entry_box_5.place(x = dx, y = 310)
        self.entry_box_6.place(x = dx, y = 340)
        self.entry_box_7.place(x = dx, y = 370 )
        

        #self.grid(row= 1, column= (counter + 2), rowspan=30)






def submit():
    W_no2 = W_no.get()
    
    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'A',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 100)
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'B',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 130)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'C',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 160)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'D',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 190)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'E',bd = 2, width = 28,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 18, y = 220)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'F',bd = 2, width = 28,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 18, y = 250)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'G',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'sky blue',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 280)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'H',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 310)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'I',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 340)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'J',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 370)    
    
    
    dx = 300 
    
    for i in range(W_no2):
        
        tk.Label(left_wl, text = i+1,bd = 2, width = 15,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "sunken").place(x = dx, y = 100)
        
        dx = dx + 150
    
    counter = 0
    columns = []  
    
    dx = 300
    while W_no2 > counter:
        columns.append(EntryRow(left_wl, counter,dx))
        print(columns)
        counter += 1
        dx += 150
    

W_Button = tk.Button ( left_wl, text = 'Sumbit', bg ='skyblue',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'), width = 15, command = submit)
W_Button.place( x = 300, y= 50)

def extract_data(columns):
    for row in columns:
        # pick the format you like more
        data_list.append((row.entry_box_1.get(), row.entry_box_2.get(), row.entry_box_3.get(),row.entry_box_4.get(),row.entry_box_5.get(),row.entry_box_6.get(),row.entry_box_7.get())) # row.entry_box_0.get(), ,row.entry_box_8.get(),row.entry_box_9.get()
        data_dict[row.entry_box_1.get()] = (row.entry_box_2.get(), row.entry_box_3.get(),row.entry_box_4.get(),row.entry_box_5.get(),row.entry_box_6.get(),row.entry_box_7.get()) # row.entry_box_1.get(),,row.entry_box_8.get(),row.entry_box_9.get()
        print(data_list)
        print(data_dict)



btn = Button(left_wl, text="Finished", command=lambda: extract_data(columns))
btn.place(x = 15, y = 400)
```

Comment: If you use `grid` or `pack` you won't have this problem. `place` is not as good for layout as the other two. Your code will be more responsive if you use one of the other geometry managers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `place()` to layout those entries, the size of the frame will not be adjusted automatically (like when `grid()` is used).

So you need to specify the width and height of the frame when you create it, like as below:

```
f = EntryRow(root, 10, 50, width=400, height=600)
```

Make sure the values of width and height are big enough to see the entries.

Comment: There is no problem with frame height

Comment: Then how do you create instance of `EntryRow`?

Comment: hey, thanks created other way but facing another problem. can you please refer the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481450/values-entered-in-the-dynamic-table-entry-widget-table-is-not-appended-in-the