# Values entered in the dynamic table (entry widget table) is not appended in the list

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

***Target of code is***: create 8 row and 'n' column table [n =1,2,3 ...n] and get the inputs entered in table cells. Use it for further calculation

**Problem :**
The below code, i have used to create a entry widgets dynamically. Tables are created successfully. But values entered in the table cells is not accessible. I have tried to create a list and append in it. but it is becoming 'none' type. so the values in the table are not able to use in further calculation.

***Working***

The sequence is :

1. Start with **submit** function; W_no2 is a int data type (1 or any
   integer) [based on this columns will be created]

2. goes to while
   loop
3. while loop to EntryRow (function)
4. coming back to while ( 3,4
   repeated until the condition fails )
5. ending while loop and goes
   to extract data function
6. stop

```
def EntryRow(left_wl, counter,dx):
        counter = counter
        dx = dx
        
        entry_box_1 = tk.Entry(left_wl)#,width=15,height = 10) # bg="lightblue")
        entry_box_2 = tk.Entry(left_wl,)# width=18,height = 10) # bg="lightblue")
        entry_box_3 = tk.Entry(left_wl,)# width=20,height = 10) # bg="lightblue")
        entry_box_4 = tk.Entry(left_wl,)# width=18,height = 10) # bg="lightblue")
        entry_box_5 = tk.Entry(left_wl,)# width=18,height = 10) # bg="lightblue")
        entry_box_6 = tk.Entry(left_wl,)# width=18,height = 10) #bg="lightblue")
        entry_box_7 = tk.Entry(left_wl, )#width=18,height = 10) #bg="lightblue")
        
        entry_box_1.place(x = dx, y = 130)# width 15, height = 10) 
        entry_box_2.place(x = dx, y = 160)
        entry_box_3.place(x = dx, y = 220)
        entry_box_4.place(x = dx, y = 250)
        entry_box_5.place(x = dx, y = 310)
        entry_box_6.place(x = dx, y = 340)
        entry_box_7.place(x = dx, y = 370 )

def submit():
    W_no2 = W_no.get()
    
    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'A',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 100)
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'B',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 130)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'C',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 160)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'D',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 190)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'E',bd = 2, width = 28,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 18, y = 220)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'F',bd = 2, width = 28,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 18, y = 250)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'G',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'sky blue',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 280)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'H',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 310)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'I',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 340)    
    tk.Label(left_wl, text = 'J',bd = 2, width = 30,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "solid").place(x = 10, y = 370)    
    
    
    dx = 300 
    
    for i in range(W_no2):
        
        tk.Label(left_wl, text = i+1,bd = 2, width = 15,bg = 'white',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'),relief = "sunken").place(x = dx, y = 100)
        
        dx = dx + 150
    
    global columns
    
    counter = 0
    columns = []  
    
    dx = 300
    while W_no2 > counter:
        columns.append(EntryRow(left_wl, counter,dx))
        print(columns)
        counter += 1
        dx += 150
    

W_Button = tk.Button ( left_wl, text = 'Sumbit', bg ='skyblue',font = ('Arial',10,'bold'), width = 15, command = submit)
W_Button.place( x = 300, y= 50)

data_dict = {}
data_list = []

def extract_data(columns):
    for row in columns:
        # pick the format you like more
        data_list.append((row.entry_box_1.get(), row.entry_box_2.get(), row.entry_box_3.get(),row.entry_box_4.get(),row.entry_box_5.get(),row.entry_box_6.get(),row.entry_box_7.get())) # row.entry_box_0.get(), ,row.entry_box_8.get(),row.entry_box_9.get()
        data_dict[row.entry_box_1.get()] = (row.entry_box_2.get(), row.entry_box_3.get(),row.entry_box_4.get(),row.entry_box_5.get(),row.entry_box_6.get(),row.entry_box_7.get()) # row.entry_box_1.get(),,row.entry_box_8.get(),row.entry_box_9.get()
        print(data_list)
        print(data_dict)



btn = Button(left_wl, text="Finished", command=lambda: extract_data(columns))
btn.place(x = 15, y = 400)
```

Comment: Is this an example we can copy and paste? Can you make it that type, so its more easier.

Comment: I did not get you. you wan to copy the code and paste and try

Answer (score 0):

You did not return anything from `EntryRow()` function, so `columns.append(EntryRow(...))` will append `None` to `columns`.

I have modified `EntryRow()` and `extract_data()` functions to use list to store those entries as below:

```py
def EntryRow(left_wl, counter, dx):
    # use list to hold the Entry widgets
    entries = []
    for y in (130, 160, 220, 250, 310, 340, 370):
        entry = tk.Entry(left_wl)
        entry.place(x=dx, y=y)
        entries.append(entry)
    # return the list of Entries
    return entries
```

```py
def extract_data(columns):
    for row in columns:
        # pick the format you like more
        data_list.append(tuple(x.get() for x in row))
        data_dict[row[0].get()] = tuple(x.get() for x in row[1:])
        print(data_list)
        print(data_dict)
```

---

If you still prefer using something like `row.entry_box_1.get()`, just modify `EntryRow()` function as below:

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace
...

def EntryRow(left_w1, counter, dx):
    row = SimpleNamespace()

    row.entry_box_1 = tk.Entry(left_wl)
    row.entry_box_2 = tk.Entry(left_wl)
    row.entry_box_3 = tk.Entry(left_wl)
    row.entry_box_4 = tk.Entry(left_wl)
    row.entry_box_5 = tk.Entry(left_wl)
    row.entry_box_6 = tk.Entry(left_wl)
    row.entry_box_7 = tk.Entry(left_wl)

    row.entry_box_1.place(x=dx, y=130)
    row.entry_box_2.place(x=dx, y=160)
    row.entry_box_3.place(x=dx, y=220)
    row.entry_box_4.place(x=dx, y=250)
    row.entry_box_5.place(x=dx, y=310)
    row.entry_box_6.place(x=dx, y=340)
    row.entry_box_7.place(x=dx, y=370)

    return row
```

And don't need to change `extract_data()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do would lend itself more to using the [grid geometry manager](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) instead of the placer geometry manager like you did.

Here's what it could look like:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

row_requester_window = tk.Tk()
row_requester_window.title('Table entry information')
row_requester_bg = ttk.Frame(row_requester_window, padding='15')
row_requester_bg.grid(column=0, row=0)

row_amount_question = ttk.Label(row_requester_bg, text='Please provide the number of rows needed:')
row_amount_question.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=15)

row_amount_value = tk.IntVar()
row_amount_answer = ttk.Entry(row_requester_bg, textvariable=row_amount_value, width=4)
row_amount_answer.grid(column=1, row=0)

row_amount_needed = 0
def select_nb_rows():
    global row_amount_needed
    row_amount_needed = row_amount_value.get()
    row_requester_window.destroy()

row_amount_decided = ttk.Button(row_requester_bg, text='OK', command=select_nb_rows)
row_amount_decided.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=1)

row_requester_window.mainloop()

table_window = tk.Tk()
table_window.title('Enter your data')
table_bg = ttk.Frame(table_window, padding='5')
table_bg.grid(column=0, row=1)

row_label_titles = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'
row_labels = [ttk.Label(table_bg, text=letter, width=3) for letter in row_label_titles]
for (current_row, current_label) in enumerate(row_labels, start=1):
    current_label.grid(column=0, row=current_row)

column_titles = [ttk.Label(table_bg, text=f'{number + 1}', width=18) for number in range(row_amount_needed)]
for (current_column, current_label) in enumerate(column_titles, start=1):
    current_label.grid(column=current_column, row=0, pady=5)

entries_values = [
    [tk.StringVar() for _ in range(row_amount_needed)]
    for _ in range(10)
]
entries_rows = [
    [ttk.Entry(table_bg, width=18, textvariable=current_variable) for current_variable in current_row]
    for current_row in entries_values
]
for (current_row_nb, current_row) in enumerate(entries_rows, start=1):
    for (current_column_nb, current_entry) in enumerate(current_row, start=1):
        current_entry.grid(column=current_column_nb, row=current_row_nb)

table_window.mainloop()

print('Grid content:')
print(
    [
        [current_value.get() for current_value in current_row]
        for current_row in entries_values
    ]
)
```